# How to get input text value from AJAX to symfony controller

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a problem to get my input text value in my controller.

This is my AJAX script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#valider').click(function () {
        var searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/firstproject/web/app_dev.php/parc/searchmodel/"+searchText,
            data:{'type':searchText},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response,xhr,status) {
                alert("erroe"+status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my <kbd>view.twig</kbd> where I have a text input:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/script.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
<input type="text" id="searchText"  name="searchText" value=" "placeholder="search by libel">
<input id="valider" type="submit" value="valider">
<h1>La liste des modeles</h1>
<table border="1">    
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Libelle</th>
        <th>pays</th>
        <th>modifier</th>
        <th>supprimer</th>
    </tr>
    {% for m in mod %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ m.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ m.libelle}}</td>
            <td>{{ m.pays }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('updatemodel',{'id':m.id}) }}">modifier</a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('deletemodel',{'id':m.id}) }}">supprimer</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This is my controller action:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request){

        $request->request->get('type');

        dump($request);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $modele = $em->getRepository("EspritParcBundle:Modele")
            ->searchbyLib($request);

        return $this->render("EspritParcBundle:Modele:searchmodel.html.twig",array('mod'=>$modele));

    }
```

This is my custom function `searchbylib`:

```
class ModeleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function searchbyLib($libele)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery('SELECT m FROM EspritParcBundle:Modele m  
                WHERE m.libelle LIKE :libele')
                ->setParameter('libele',$libele);

        dump($em->getResult());
        return $em->getResult();    
    }
}
```

And finally, my routing file:

```
searchmodel:
    path:     /searchmodel/{type}
    defaults: { _controller: EspritParcBundle:Modele:search}
```

This is my output:

[image]

When entering "BMW" in the text field then click on the validation button, I would like it to show me only BMW models and the url to be redirected.

Comment: alert(searchText); what you give ?

Comment: it gives me the value of text input

Comment: try to delete "dump($em->getResult());" and "dump($request);"

Comment: i have add dump to my code just to show the object what it contains the problem isnt there

Comment: i delete dump and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

view.html.twig

```
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
       <script src="{{ asset('bundles/js/script.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
<form action="{{ path('searchmodel') }}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="searchText"  name="searchText" value=" "placeholder="search by libel">
        <input id="valider" type="submit" value="valider">
    </form>
    <h1>La liste des modeles</h1>
    <table border="1">

        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Libelle</th>
            <th>pays</th>
            <th>modifier</th>
            <th>supprimer</th>
        </tr>

        {% for m in mod %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ m.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ m.libelle}}</td>
                <td>{{ m.pays }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('updatemodel',{'id':m.id}) }}">modifier</a>
                </td>
                <td><a href="{{ path('deletemodel',{'id':m.id}) }}">supprimer</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

routing file:

```
searchmodel:
path:     /searchmodel
defaults: { _controller: EspritParcBundle:Modele:search}
```

controller :

```
public function searchAction(Request $request){

    $request = $request->get('type');


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $modele = $em->getRepository("EspritParcBundle:Modele")
        ->searchbyLib($request);

    return $this->render("path:to:view.html.twig",array('mod'=>$modele));

}
```

Comment: same problem  nothing change

Comment: you have try to change the url ??

Comment: i have post my output picture try to take a look mybe you get the problem

Comment: same problem my page is not redirected vers thne new url and when i tape the url manually there is nothing to display its empty

Comment: if you want to redirected to a new page you don't have to use ajax

Comment: what should i do give me the easiest way to redirect to the new url and get my data displayed

Comment: return $this->render("path:to:view.html.twig",array('mod'=>$modele));
 what does it means ? which templte you mean ?

Comment: juste chnage path:to with your path "EspritParcBundle:Modele" for exemple

Comment: the lis template or search template N

Comment: try with the list template :p

Comment: http://localhost/firstproject/web/app_dev.php/parc/searchmodel  the url change but there is no results to display its empty :3

Answer (score 0):

The $type parameter is passed through the query string

```
searchmodel:
    path:     /searchmodel/{type}
    defaults: { _controller: EspritParcBundle:Modele:search}
```

So you can directly add it to the parameter of the method like this :

```
public function searchAction(Request $request, $type)
{



    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $modele = $em->getRepository("EspritParcBundle:Modele")
        ->searchbyLib($request);

    return $this->render("path:to:view.html.twig",array('mod'=>$modele));

}
```

Is that help you?

Comment: no man nothing change there is no display and also my url didnt change

Comment: Well, i think at first there is a miss on the using of the ajax here. You are trying to use the post on a route which returns html.
Why don't you use a form with standard feature from symfony and then manage your postData through a form.
You have the same route which does 2 things i think this is not the best way to do.
For the input field, imo i used a select field with all the name of your model (with a unique filter for duplicates), you will not have to manage a like in your query and use a findBy function.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my controller `$request = $request->get('type');` always return `null`, so I've tried with `$lib = $request->getContent();` and then I did `dump($lib);` to display what it contains and here is the output:

[image]

So after that, I used `substr` function to extract only the text value and delete the rest and everything is working well.